# The name 'ParameterDirection' does not exist in the current context using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

Tags: asp.net, .net, oracle, oracle11g

I am testing to get the id of an inserted row with dotnet with the package on the title (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client) but when I try to specify the Parameter Direction the class is not recognized and get the error The name 'ParameterDirection' does not exist in the current context. I am using .NET 3.1
I am trying to specify it like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":id", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.output));
```

Does the package not include the class ParameterDirection? Do I need another one?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ParameterDirection` enumerator is available under the `System.Data` namespace. Please, make sure you are using this namespace.

```
using System.Data;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
```

And try

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":id", 
                                       OracleDbType.Int32, 
                                       ParameterDirection.Output));
```

Comment: It's always the simplest of solutions haha thanks for answering